# am trying to integrate localytics but nothing is showing on localytics dashboard

Tags: java, android, api, integration, localytics

Below is the code of but its not showing any thing into dashboard.
in localytics logs am getting data uploaded.

Here is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       setIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

this is my application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(
             new LocalyticsActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this));
    }
}
```

Manifest permissions are also added.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to try and help out here. I'm not seeing where you provided the app key e.g.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="LOCALYTICS_APP_KEY"
        android:value="24bda322df2a476a44c2510-55321786-060f-11e5-9c94-00739d24cb12" />
```

This could be the cause for the data never arriving in the Localytics dashboard. But let me know what you think!

Tom

Comment: sorry to say but i forgot to mention meta-data here, and my code is working now, the problem is cause of some delay in LOCALYTICS server. anywys thanks